# IndexError: list index out of range even though requested index is within the range

Tags: regex, python-2.7

This is the code I ran

```
fname = raw_input('Enter file name: ')
if ( len(fname) < 1 ) : fname = 'shi.txt'
fh = open(fname)

for line in fh:
    email=re.findall('^From (.*)',line)
    print len(email)
    print email[0]

    x=email[0]
```

This is the output and error I'm getting

```
Enter file name: shi.txt
1
stephen.marquard@uct.ac.za Sat Jan  5 09:14:16 2008
0

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\Shivam\Desktop\test1.py", line 21, in <module>
print email[0]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

My issue is that as in the output you can see email[0] shouldn't be out of index but still I'm getting this error even after email[0] is actually being printed.Moreover I don't understand why am I getting this 0 output after printing email[0].My code isn't getting executed after that.This is snippet of a sqlite access code.Thanks in advance

Comment: Why do you say it shouldn't be out of range? You just printed `len(email)` on the line above it, and it was 0.

Comment: It seems you're confused about the for loop. That loops over every line in the file, and apparently there's more than one line. It's the second line that is causing the problem. The 0 printed after the email is the length of `email` the *second* time through the loop (the second line of the file).

Comment: Oh I get it now.Because the second line doesn't contain any string satisfying the condition it's returning an empty list.That should've been easy one.Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

Your code contains a `for` loop iterating through all the lines in the file.

The first line starts with "From " and thus satisfies the `^From (.*)` regex, and thus the first line parsing results in Count = 1 and the captured group value is printed (`re.findall` only returns captured values if capture groups are defined in the pattern).

The second line cannot be matched by your regex, and thus `re.findall` resultung list is empty. Thus, you get an error.

To work around that issue and check all the lines, just make sure you check the length before accessing the first item in the list:

```
for line in fh:
    email=re.findall('^From (.*)',line)
    if len(email) > 0:
        print email[0]
```

Note that there is no point in using `re.findall` here since the match will always be single. You may use `re.search`, check if there was a match, and print the contents of the match:

```
for line in fh:
    email=re.search(r'^From (.*)', line) # get the match object
    if email:                            # if the match is not none
        print email.group(0)             # print Group 0 (match value)
```